# Sending email using Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a simple email notification using 2 conditions in Google spreadsheet. I created for I function so that it will scan the rows I needed for my if condition. If `challengeStatus` and `challengeSent` are met, it will send an email notification. The email works fine, however, every time I run the function, it won't be finished running the code. Looks like there is a problem with my loop statement somewhere but can't figure it out. Here is my code please help.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Challenges");
 var lr= ss.getLastRow();  

for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++) {
 var qaEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()
 var adminEmail = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue()
  var VideoId = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue()
   var QA1comment = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue()
   var QA2comment = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue()
   var QA3comment = ss.getRange(i, 12).getValue()
   var challengeStatus = ss.getRange(i, 13).getValue()
   var challengeSent = ss.getRange(i, 14).getValue()
   var subject,mailbody
 subject = "Challenge Result: ("+ VideoId + ")";
   mailbody = 'Hi, ' +adminEmail+ ' <br><br>This email is to notify you that we have completed to process your dispute on Video Id: <b>' +VideoId+ '</b> and the result is <b>' +challengeStatus+ '</b>.<br><br> Scores will be updated based on the result. <br><br>Comments: <br><br> QA 1: ' +QA1comment+' <br><br>QA 2: ' +QA2comment+'<br><br> QA 3: ' +QA3comment+' <br><br>Thank you. <br><br>Quality Team';

   if (challengeStatus =="Non Revert" && challengeSent ==""){

   MailApp.sendEmail(adminEmail,subject," ",{
       name: 'Quality Team (No Reply)',
       cc: qaEmail,
       htmlBody: mailbody,
       });     

     //Logger.log(VideoId);
   }
  }
  sendstatus = ss.getRange('N' + i).setValue('Sent')
}
```

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet

Comment: Add the execution transcript and the results on the executions page for the script on https://script.google.com

Comment: How many rows does your Sheet have? Your code worked fine for me. Also, don't forget to put semicolons `;` at the end of each statement.